# Copy data every 1 minute from DataLake by DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a Data Lake storage with the following folder structure:

```
{YEAR}
 - {MONTH}
  - {DAY}
   - {HOUR}
     - {sometext}_{YEAR}_{MONTH}_{DAY}_{HOUR}_{Minute}_{someuuid}.json
```

example

[image]

Could you please help me to configure Data Factory Copy data action?
I need to run Trigger every 1 minute - to copy data from Data Lake by previous minute to Cosmos DB
I've tried this
[image]
where the first expresion is

```
@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy/MM/dd/HH')
```

and the second one

```
@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy')}_@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM')}_@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd')}_@{formatDateTime(utcnow(),'HH')}_@{formatDateTime(addMinutes(utcnow(), -1),'mm')}*.json
```

But it can skip some data, especially when Hour changes.
I'm a new in Data Factory and don't know what is the more efficient way how to do that. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pipeline Expression Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) has a number of [Date functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#date-functions) built in. You can use the [addMinutes function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#addMinutes) to add 1 minute.

To avoid clock skew, I would capture the utcnow() value and store it without any formatting:

[image]

In another variable, add a minute to the captured value rather than executing utcnow() again:

[image]

Once you have those variables, just use them to format the date string(s).
[image]

Result:

[image]

NOTE: use concat with the formatDateString to get the wildcard value you want:
[image]

Result:

[image]